# Getting Error while creating new project using angular cli 6.0.8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular6

i have recently upgarded my angular cli to the latest version. But when creating new project using angular cli getting this errors

```
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump

added 1113 packages from 1284 contributors and audited 21849 packages in 235.594s
found 13 vulnerabilities (9 low, 4 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: ```npm cache clean --force```

Comment: i have tried this but nothing happen